# Admin, filtering posts list with INNER JOIN

Tags: wordpress

I'm developing a WordPress plugin in which I have created custom posts and used metadata to link them together.

On the admin side, I want to be able to filter posts list using those relations. I guess I would need to use INNER JOIN but I don't know how.

For now, all I have is:

```
add_filter( 'parse_query', 'mypostsfilteringfunction' );
function mypostsfilteringfunction( $query ){
        
        // if post_type matches : 
        // then I need to be able to add innerjoin into $query

}
```

Answer (score 1):

A achieve my goal by doing :

```
add_filter( 'parse_query', 'mypostsfilteringfunction' );
function mypostsfilteringfunction( $query ){    
    // if post_type matches : 
    add_filter( 'posts_join', 'myplugin_addjointorequest' );
    add_filter( 'posts_where', 'myplugin_addwheretorequest' );
    add_filter( 'posts_request', 'myplugin_sqlprint' ); // for printing result
}
function myplugin_addjointorequest ($join){
    $join .= 'INNER JOIN ...'; 
    return $join;   
}
function myplugin_addwheretorequest ($where){
    $where .= 'AND ...'; 
    return $where;   
}
function myplugin_sqlprint( $request ) {
    echo $request;
    return $request;
}
```